# How to use the API using only the API key

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to run the Compute Engine API from my home machine using curl (don't use gconsole or sdks).
I can get response using OAuth 2.0 access, but can't get response using only api-key.
Can I use the API using only the API key?

- success

request

```
curl https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/zones/{ZONE}/instances/{INSTANCE_ID} 'Authorization: Bearer [ACCESS_TOKEN]'
```

- failed

request

```
curl https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/zones/{ZONE}/instances/{INSTANCE_ID}?key={MY_API_KEY}
```

response

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Google Compute Engine API does not support API Keys for authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between public and private data.  Public data is data that is not owned by anyone and is there for public.  TO access public data you can use an api key.

Some methods however are private user data and in order to access them you need to be authorized to access that data

if you check the documentation for the method [projects/get](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/get) you will see that it states

which is exactly what your error message is telling you

> Request is missing required authentication credential.

So the answer is you cant.  You cant use an API key to access private user data you must be authorized.

[image]

Its telling you that this method is user data and there for requires authorization in order to access use it.

Comment: i need to use  OAuth 2.0 to access the private api's. thank you +1